# Why Catboost is giving error with MultiClass

Tags: multiclass-classification, boosting

I am trying [Catboost](https://tech.yandex.com/catboost/doc/dg/concepts/python-usages-examples-docpage/#multiclassification) package with `iris` dataset with following code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris  
iris = load_iris()
from catboost import CatBoostClassifier
model = CatBoostClassifier(iterations=2, learning_rate=1, 
             depth=2, loss_function='MultiClass')
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
scores = cross_val_score(model, iris.data, iris.target)
print(scores)
```

It starts to run but then throws an error:

```
0:      learn: -0.2870345       total: 46.4ms   remaining: 46.4ms
1:      learn: -0.1884151       total: 47ms     remaining: 0us
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "catboost_test.py", line 7, in <module>
    scores = cross_val_score(model, iris.data, iris.target)
  File "/home/abcd/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 342, in cross_val_score
    pre_dispatch=pre_dispatch)
  File "/home/abcd/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 206, in cross_validate
    for train, test in cv.split(X, y, groups))
  File "/home/abcd/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 779, in __call__
    while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
  File "/home/abcd/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 625, in dispatch_one_batch
    self._dispatch(tasks)
  File "/home/abcd/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 588, in _dispatch
    job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
  File "/home/abcd/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 111, in apply_async
    result = ImmediateResult(func)
  File "/home/abcd/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 332, in __init__
    self.results = batch()
  File "/home/abcd/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 131, in __call__
    return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "/home/abcd/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 131, in <listcomp>
    return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "/home/abcd/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 488, in _fit_and_score
    test_scores = _score(estimator, X_test, y_test, scorer, is_multimetric)
  File "/home/abcd/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 523, in _score
    return _multimetric_score(estimator, X_test, y_test, scorer)
  File "/home/abcd/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 553, in _multimetric_score
    score = scorer(estimator, X_test, y_test)
  File "/home/abcd/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/scorer.py", line 244, in _passthrough_scorer
    return estimator.score(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/abcd/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/catboost/core.py", line 2285, in score
    for i, val in enumerate(self.predict(X)):
  File "/home/abcd/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/catboost/core.py", line 2156, in predict
    return self._predict(data, prediction_type, ntree_start, ntree_end, thread_count, verbose)
  File "/home/abcd/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/catboost/core.py", line 1237, in _predict
    return np.transpose(self._base_predict_multi(data, prediction_type, ntree_start, ntree_end, thread_count, verbose))
  File "/home/abcd/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/catboost/core.py", line 875, in _base_predict_multi
    return self._object._base_predict_multi(pool, prediction_type, ntree_start, ntree_end, thread_count, verbose)
  File "_catboost.pyx", line 1518, in _catboost._CatBoost._base_predict_multi
  File "_catboost.pyx", line 1533, in _catboost._CatBoost._base_predict_multi
  File "_catboost.pyx", line 1817, in _catboost._convert_to_visible_labels
_catboost.CatboostError: catboost/libs/labels/external_label_helper.cpp:78: Can't convert bad label back to class name.
```

It runs all right with binary targets, for example, if I use only the first 100 rows of iris data (which have 2 classes).

The same error is thrown if the `wine` dataset is used. Also, there are 3 classes in target and it runs all right if I use only the first 130 rows which have only 2 classes.

Why `catboost` is not working with the `MultiClass` option? Thanks for your insight.

Edit: Catboost version is:

```
In [1]: import catboost
In [2]: print(catboost.__version__)
0.10.2
```

Comment: Mine is working just fine. You may update update the Catboost. Or it is best to include the version of your python, catboost in the original Q.

Comment: Catboost versionis 0.10.2

Comment: I just tested. I have had version 0.9 works just fine. Also now upgraded to the last 0.11.2 version, also works. Something is wrong with your env.

Comment: Yes, it works after upgrading. But `scores` is coming as `[0. 0. 0.]`. I expected these valuee to be close to `1`.

Comment: Well, that is ia different story. Still mine does not come out zll zeros. Try these e.g. depth=4, iterations=500, learning_rate=0.1. These shouldn't give you all zeros!

Comment: It is still `[0. 0. 0.]`. Why this is so difficult even with simple problems?